# Beamer presentation with page containing Latex output

Tags: beamer

Latex newbie here.
Let's say I create a page with some Latex code, and I want to have the following beamer slide contain the output of that code. how can I do that?

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{How does \mbox{\LaTeX} work?}
\begin{verbatim} 
\title{My R Poem}
\author{Dude}

\begin{document}

R is my favoritest.

\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
```

I assume there's a package for this, but I'm not aware of it and can't find it via google.

Comment: Do you want to show code and result side-by-side or just the output?

Comment: I'd have the code on one slide, which is done with the verbatim package (see code above), and another slide for the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include the output of a different, full document with own preamble you would have to include the output as PDF (or PS if you insist using non-PDF `latex`). I would recommend you to store the code in an external file and use the `standalone` class to produce a tightly cut PDF (the `preview` package is internally used to do this). Then simply include the PDF as graphic using `\includegraphics[width=...]{filename}`. You can also include the source using the `listings` package and `\lstinputlisting`. It also allows you to remove the first or last code lines if you want to remove the `\documentclass[class=<realclass>]{standalone}` part.

The v1.0 of the `standalone` package allows to automatically compile sub-files as standalone documents and include them as images to the main document.